# $_GET method vulnerabilities

Tags: php, http

If I use `$_GET` function to send passwords, then apart from the fact that the password will be visible in my browser's address bar, are there any more security vulnerabilities which are not already there in `$_POST` method ? Because in any case the password will only be visible in the users' browser and not to anyone else.

Comment: And in proxy log, and in user's browser history, ... Just don't do that

Comment: yeah, not a good idea. +1 @zerkms

Comment: At least MD5 it before you put it in the URL if you really must.

Comment: in case of 'men in the middle' that can listen to the transffer, it get the password to avoid that use ssl protocol

Comment: RESTfully speaking if you are authenticating/signing in a user you should be using POST. If you are creating a new user you should be using PUT. The GET verb is used to fetching. It must not have any side effects.

Comment: if they log on from any computer that is not their own personal computer then their information will be exposed unless they take the necessary steps to clear the browser, in which the average user may not be aware to do so, and when someone logs into a site, they expect their information to be secure. the user should not have to take unnecessary steps like clearing the browser, although they may want to anyway.

Comment: more specifically, is there a reason as to why you prefer to use GET as opposed to POST, if you are having an issue there, we may be able to help.

Comment: @mcbeav No, there is no reason to prefer GET as opposed to POST. It was just out of curiosity. Just wanted to know if there are any more vulnerabilities in using GET method to send sensitive data, apart from the data visible in the address bar. I know POST method isn't secure either. I just wanted to know if there are any more  differences in terms of security between the two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$_GET` Method the website url `will be logged in history or browser and proxy servers` this won't possible with `$_POST`.

in `$_GET` password is appened in URL and `$_POST` password is sent in next packet so in both method password is sent in clear-text so solution is `$_POST` with [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL) to encrypt the communication.

Comment: It's kind of obvious, but I didn't even think of GET vars being saved in history when I wrote my answer. Good catch, man. +1

Answer (score 2):

Even if you send a password using POST it will be sent as plain text. If you want to send it securely you should use SSL.

Comment: even a POST with ssl is vulnerable to "man in the middle" attacks, cain & able does this well

Comment: ^ that is clients duty to secure his login.

Comment: @Lawerence Yes I know nothing is bulletproof. There are keyloggers, screencapturers, social engineering, someone may be watching over your shoulder, etc. but using ssl will prevent eavesdropping with some degree of confidence.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use POST to submit values, but in the end, everything is submitted data. Either provided through POST or GET, it's essential to sanitize.

Answer (score 0):

You really should send login information via POST. As you said, GET values are passed via the URL. POST values are sent via the HTTP request headers. While not "secure" it's a little more transparent than having it in the URL.

The best method for you is to submit it via POST and use SSL so the information isn't transmitted in cleartext accross the wire.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you some thing i found very use full and that is 
pleas

> http://phpsec.org/projects/

hope that helps.